# Reload javascript function on condition

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can reload a javascript function on an if condition?
For example say I have a function

```
runCode(){
    //do something
}
```

Firsty I tried

```
setInterval(function(){
  runCode();
},1000);
```

but I do not want it to reload on a certain period of time, but on an if condition.

Let us say that I have a function which will sometimes return true, sometimes false, based on what the user inputs in a textarea (for example !). So in this situation I want to be able to check if it changed to true or viceversa after the user's input and if it is true I need to reload the function `runCode()`

Comment: you can definitely do it.. call that function inside an if scope..

Comment: What is your condition?

Comment: Please clarify your question. You accepted an answer which merely wraps the function call in an `if` statement. That either executes the function right now, or not, and that's it. It does not "watch" the condition and execution your function when the condition becomes true--which is what I personally imagined you might be asking when I read your question. Could you be more specific about what you want?

Comment: @torazaburo I accepted the answer because it works.The problem is that it takes very long to execute and I'm not sure why. Let us say that I have a function which  will sometimes return true, sometimes false, based on what the user inputs in a textarea (for example !). So in this situation I want to be able to check if it changed to true or viceversa after the user's input and if it is true I need to reload the function `runCode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
if (expression) {
    runcode();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by this answer, and more so why it would be accepted. From the OP's question it sounds like he's looking for an **alternative** to a waiting duration, in other words, waiting for a condition to be fulfilled rather than waiting for some specified period of time. That sounds like promises to me.

Comment: I answered what I understood was questioned.

Comment: We'll have to wait for him to clarify, but the word "reload" seems like a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes..
You can call that function inside an if scope..

```
if(condition){
runCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setter to run function after change value:

```
function sayHello(){
  alert('hello!');
}

Object.defineProperty(window, 'condVar', {
  get: function() {
    return this._condVar;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    if(value === 123)
      sayHello();
    this._condVar = value;

  }
});

alert('setting 123');
condVar = 123;

alert('setting abc');
condVar = 'abc';

alert('setting 123');
condVar = 123;
```

More about setter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set